# Append a child to a grid, set it's row and column

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, gridview

How can I append an `Image` object into a `Grid` and set it's **Row** and **Column**?

The grid is 3x3.

Main file:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="440" Width="400" ResizeMode="NoResize">
    <Window.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="C:\Users\GuyD\AppData\Local\Temporary Projects\WpfApplication1\AppResources\Background.png"></ImageBrush>
    </Window.Background>
    <Grid ShowGridLines="True" x:Name="myGrid">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="42" />
            <RowDefinition Height="30*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="30*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="32*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="31*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="26*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="32*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code behind file:

```
public MainWindow()
{
     InitializeComponent();
     for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
     {
          for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
          {
               Image Box = new Image();
               this.myGrid.Children.Add(Box);
          }
     }
}
```

Comment: To better understand you question, do you want to control the height & width of each cell of the grid using c# code?

Comment: I want to add a child element, and set it's row and column

Answer (score 64, accepted):

The Grid setter methods are static.
To place them in row 1 column 1:

```
Image Box = new Image();
myGrid.Children.Add(Box);
Grid.SetRow(Box, 1);
Grid.SetColumn(Box, 1);
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use following to set for any UIElement

```
Grid.SetRow(Box, i);
Grid.SetColumn(Box, j);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
      {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
           Image Box = new Image();
           this.myGrid.Children.Add(Box);
           Grid.SetRow(Box, i);
           Grid.SetColumn(Box, j);
        }
     }
```

And yes the Grid is of 4X3 not of 3X3 dimensions. I hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public MainWindow() {
 InitializeComponent();
 for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
 {
      for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
      {
           Image Box = new Image();
           Grid.SetRow(Box, i);
           Grid.SetColumn(Box, j);
      }
 }
}
```